# Conda Build Setuptools downloading is Disabled Error

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I want to create a Conda Package from my python library on Windows, but `conda build .` gives me the error

```
Processing dependencies for communicator==0.1.0
Searching for isodate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 39, in <module>
    tests_require=test_requirements,
  ...
    "Be sure to add all dependencies in the meta.yaml  url=%s" % url)
RuntimeError: Setuptools downloading is disabled in conda build. Be sure to add all dependencies in the meta.yaml  url=https://pypi.org/simple/isodate/
```

This is my `meta.yaml`:
I also added the `isodate` to the the `host` and `run` and also to the `tests` section.

```
{% set data = load_setup_py_data() %}

package:
  name: communicator
  version: {{ data['version'] }}

source:
  path: ..

build:
  number: 0

requirements:
  host:
    - python
    - pip
    - rdflib
    - isodate
  run:
    - python
    - rdflib
    - isodate

test:
  source_files:
    - tests
  commands:
    - {{ PYTHON }} -m unittest discover
  requires:
    - rdflib
    - isodate

about:
  home: https://example.com/
  summary: {{ data['description'] }}
  license: {{ data['license'] }}
  license_file: LICENSE
```

And this is my `bld.bat`:

```
"%PYTHON%" setup.py install
if errorlevel 1 exit 1
```

And this is my `setup.py`:
I also added the `isodate` to the the `requirements` list.

```
from setuptools import setup

requirements = ["rdflib", "isodate"]

test_requirements = []

setup(
    name="communicator",
    version="0.1.0",
    description="Package to query the Triple Store for Workflow Configuration Details.",
    long_description=readme + "\n\n" + history,
    author="User",
    author_email="email",
    url="https://example.com",
    packages=["communicator",],
    package_dir={"communicator": "communicator"},
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=requirements,
    license="MIT license",
    zip_safe=False,
    keywords="communicator",
    classifiers=[
        ...
    ],
    test_suite="tests",
    tests_require=test_requirements,
)
```

As you can see i have added `isodate` in the `meta.yaml` and also in the `setup.py` but `conda build .` still gives me that error.
Did i forget something to add? Or is there a better way to structure the `meta.yaml`?

Comment: What happens if you delete the `tests_require` from your `setup()` call?

Comment: i'm still getting the error after i deleted the `tests_require` from my `setup.py`

Comment: Dang... Is `isodate` being installed by Conda during the build process? Can you post the complete build process output?

Comment: yes its in every environment created by conda listed

Comment: Can you post the complete output from `conda build`?